# visited link has unwanted text decoration

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a link and I want it to transition into another color when I hover over it. When I click it however, it should go back to normal, like before I hovered over it.

```
a {
  -o-transition:.3s;
  -ms-transition:.3s;
  -moz-transition:.3s;
  -webkit-transition:.3s;
  transition:.3s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

a:hover { 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #66caff; 
}
```

It's working fine when I hover, but after I visit the link, I'm getting unwanted underlines, and it changes to purple. It should look as it did before I clicked it.

```
a:visited { 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff; 
}
```

Adding this prevents any color transition from taking place, and the visited link is still being underlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pseudo-classes on anchors (*links*) should be declared in a specific order. The order is: Link, Visited, Hover, Active.

Shift your `:visited` rule before the `:hover` one and it will work.

**Snippet:**

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none; color: #0f0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

a:visited { color: #0f0; }
a:hover { color: #f00; }
```

```html
<a href="#">Link 1</a> | <a href="#">Link 2</a>
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Avisited

> ...This style may be overridden by any other link-related
>   pseudo-classes, that is :link, :hover, and :active, appearing in
>   subsequent rules. In order to style appropriately links, you need to
>   put the :visited rule after the :link rule but before the other ones,
>   defined in the LVHA-order: :link — :visited — :hover — :active.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine. I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0m4gcab/) from your code.

```
   HTML : 
   <a href="/">VISIT</a>
```

CSS is same as you have mentioned in the question. It works fine for me.  Please mention the OS and browser you are using to test your code and the versions of the same. It could be an issue specific to that particular version or OS.